# Need some kind of pivotal table without agregation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I struck with problem of getting reports from table, that look like this:

```
C1| C2         | C3 | C4
A | 2015-05-15 | 34 | 4
A | 2015-03-12 | -4 | 5
A | 2014-03-12 | 24 | 8
B | 2015-11-10 | -4 | 5
B | 2015-06-12 | 3 | 5
C | 2013-05-12 | 3 | 5
...
600+ rows
...
```

So I need to make a diagram by different value columns (C3 and C4) grouping by values in the first column. In usual case it is achieved with to separate table which a looks like this (e.g. for col3):

```
A  |  B  |  C  | ....
34 |  -4 |  3  | ....
-4 |  3  |     | ....
24 |     |     | ....
```

For col4, I need a table with the similar layout. So in short, I need to make some pivotal table by without aggregation on value per term. Is it possible to get such small table with the original table? If you can offer some other layout for original data which will be more suitable (and easier, in ideal with standard excel functions) for this task, fell free to offer - with some Python script I can resave it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will assume that `C1,C2,C3,C4` are column headings in A1:D1 and the data is in A2:D1000

1. In F1:H1 place `C3,C3,C3`
2. In F2:H2 place `A,B,C`
3. In J1:L1 place `C4,C4,C4`
4. In J2:L2 place `A,B,C`
5. In F3 place the following array formula:

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$2:$A$1000,0,MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)-1),SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$1000=F$2,ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(F$2:F2))),"")
   ```

   Don't forget to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an array formula instead of just using <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a normal formula.
6. Copy F3 to F4:F7, G3:H7 and J3:L7

You end up with something that looks like this:

```
    | A             B     C     D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L
----|--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | C1           C2    C3    C4        C3   C3   C3        C4   C4   C4
2   | A    15/05/2015    34     4        A     B    C         A    B    C
3   | A    12/03/2015    -4     5        34   -4    3         4    5    5
4   | A    12/03/2014    24     8        -4    3              5    5     
5   | B    10/11/2015    -4     5        24                   8          
6   | B    12/06/2015     3     5                                        
7   | C    12/05/2013     3     5
```

Decomposing the formula in F3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(source column,SMALL(filtered row numbers,ranking)),"")
```

Where:

- source column is `OFFSET($A$2:$A$1000,0,MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)-1)`
- filtered row numbers is `IF($A$2:$A$1000=F$2,row numbers)`
- row numbers is `ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1`
- ranking is `ROWS(F$2:F2)`

How the formula works is a multipart explanation:

- `IFERROR(formula,"")`  If the embedded formula produces an error then we display an empty cell instead.  This is useful since we don't know how many results we will get.
- `INDEX(range,row)`  Get the value in the row we want to see.  The row number here is dynamically generated based on whether the data matches the criteria.
- `SMALL(array,k)`  Extract the kth smallest value in the array.  The array is the filtered values.  k is just a number depending on which row in F we put the formula in.
- `IF(criteria,value)`  Based on the criteria either produces the value or FALSE.
- `ROW(cell)`  The row number of the cell
- `ROWS(range)`  The size of the range

So in the array formula:

- `ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1` is a list of all the row numbers in the range starting at 1
- `IF($A$2:$A$1000=F$2,ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1)` is a list of just those row numbers that match the criteria
- `SMALL` takes the filtered list and returns the kth smallest filtered row number which means that F3 gets the first one, F4 gets the second one, etc
- `INDEX` grabs the data at that row number and displays it

I got the idea for this from http://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/ and on that page is a really good explanation of how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Find a simple solution: just download tool [Tableau](http://tableau.com). It affords to create very flexible graphs based on raw data, freely place any col as row and vice versa, groping also available.